# Windows Forms: 'Input string was not in a correct format' error

Tags: c#, winforms, input, int, user-input

I am creating a webpage re-loader and I am trying to get number of reload using input from user but I am not able to get number of input from user.

I am trying to get user input in `textBox2.Text`, but I am having this error:

```
input string was not in a currect format
```

This error is in this line `kkk = System.Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);`

please help me how to get user input properly in an `int` value.

this is my program code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public  int kkk;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != kkk)
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
                    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        if(webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                        {
                            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("failed");
                }
            }
            while(progressBar1.Value !=kkk);
        }   
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        kkk = System.Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        progressBar1.Maximum = kkk;        
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

}
```

Comment: in your form load event you take the contents of textbox2. text and assign it to kkk.  But at that point nothing is inside textBox2 so it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your form load event you take the contents of textbox2. text and assign it to kkk. But at that point nothing is inside textBox2 so it throws the error, and rightfully so since the textbox is empty how can it parse to an Int32 if it has no value?

You should assign the value of `kkk` at some later time during the process.  You can always handle the exception before it happens:

```
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtBox2.Text, out number);
  if (result)
  {
    //good conversion you can use number
  }
  else
  {
    //not so good
  }
```

But again you are doing this at form load event and I highly doubt there is anything in that textbox based on your code by the time the load event is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
kkk = System.Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

is giving an error maybe because it is an empty string which is unable to get parsed to integer. Change it to:

```
kkk = textBox2.Text.Trim();
if( kkk.Length > 0 ) {
    try {
        kkk = System.Int32.Parse(kkk);
    }
    catch { }
}
```